# Salesforce APEX get users User License

Tags: salesforce, apex

So I am trying to get the current users User License eg. System Administrator or User etc... I have look through here and used other methods however these don't seem to work for me. I was wondering where I could make a start towards this?

The error I get is:

> Comparison arguments must be compatible types: Schema.SObjectField, String

From using the following code:

```
public String getOpps() {
    if(Profile.UserLicense.Name === 'Community Customer') {
        oppCheck = true;
    } else {
        oppCheck = false;
    }


    ***loop*** {
            code here
        }
    } else {
       more code here
    }
    return 'nil';
 }
```

Comment: Just to clarify, System Administrator vs User is a profile, not a user license. A license determines things like Salesforce vs Chatter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the license types, I got them from the API guide [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm) thanks to [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/3895/).

> - **Standard**: user license. This user type also includes Salesforce Platform and Salesforce Platform One user licenses. Label is Standard.
> - **PowerPartner**: PRM user whose access is limited because he or she is a partner and typically accesses the application through a partner
>     portal. Label is Partner.
> - **CSPLitePortal**: user whose access is limited because he or she is an organization's customer and accesses the application through
>     aCustomer Portal. Label is High Volume Portal.
> - **CustomerSuccess**: user whose access is limited because he or she is an organization's customer and accesses the application through a
>     Customer Portal. Label is Customer Portal User.
> - **PowerCustomerSuccess**: user whose access is limited because he or she is an organization's customer and accesses the application through
>     a Customer Portal. Label is Customer Portal Manager. Users with this
>     license type can view and edit data they directly own or data owned by
>     or shared with users below them in the Customer Portal role hierarchy.
> - **CsnOnly**: user whose access to the application is limited to Chatter. This user type includes Chatter Free and Chatter moderator
>     users. Label is Chatter Free.

Also, you might have some luck trying:

```
Profile p = [Select Name from Profile where Id =: userinfo.getProfileid()];
String pname = p.name;

if(pname == 'Community Customer') {
    oppCheck = true;
} else {
    oppCheck = false;
}
```